# Hook into Outlook events

Tags: c++, import, outlook

I'm working on an application that captures some Outlook events. I recently installed MS Office 2010 x64, and since that moment I'm no longer able to compile my project, I don't know if this information helps to resolve the problem. I'm getting errors related to `msoutl.tlh` file.

> error C2371: '_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer' : redefinition;
>   different basic types

Here is my import statement :

```
#import "libid:00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" 
    no_namespace auto_rename auto_search exclude("Folder") 
    use rename("Folder","OutlookFolder") 
    raw_interfaces_only rename("Rectangle","msw_Rectangle") 
    rename("ExitWindows","msw_ExitWindows") 
    rename("FindText","msw_FindText") 
    rename ("GetOrganizer","GetOrganizerEA")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that I had two registy keys with the same libid and that's what confused the compiler. I simply deleted one of them.